# ETC1 texture support on Samsung Galaxy ACE GT-S5830

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I have this Samsung Galaxy ACE GT-S5830 android phone.
which has an Adreno-200 GPU.

I would have expected it to have the ETC (Ericsson Compression format) support,
but looks like it cannot load them.

Although the gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS) function contains the GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture extension.

but the android.opengl.ETC1Util.isETC1Supported() returns false ???
This is so strange.

I have converted my files to .pkm format.
This is how i am loading the texture, but all i see is the white-screen indicating the texture is not loaded. :

```
InputStream is= _context.getAssets().open("etc/hands_tex.pkm");                     
gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);   //texture unit to load texture to.
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextureId);
try {
    ETC1Texture etc1tex = ETC1Util.createTexture(is);               
    ByteBuffer bb = etc1tex.getData();              
    gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES, etc1tex.getWidth(), etc1tex.getHeight(), 0, bb.capacity(), bb);                
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Even though the call to ETC1Util.createTexture() above works and creates the texture object in memory.

Comment: Are you calling ETC1Util.isETC1Supported() within the valid OpenGL ES 1.x context? If you have not created OpenGL context, then it will return false.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Java GL but i've written native OpenGL code for Android that uses ETC1 compression so hopefully i can help. ETC1 is the common texture compression format for Android and having the extension present shows that your device supports it. :)

There are a few unknowns here that you should try and resolve.

It might be your texture loading and display code is faulty, not the ETC1 part. So you should probably try swapping out ETC1 and use a non-compressed safe format such as 32bit to 
check that displays correctly.

Then try using a simple 32x32 ETC1 texture to remove non-square NPOT sizes having a influence. Use hard-coded values for the *glCompressedTexImage2D* call:

```
gl.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES, 32, 32, 0, 512, bb);
```

Make sure *bb* is valid if course as NULL is a valid parameter.
The return code from *glCompressedTexImage2D* is also very useful too.

Apologies if you've already tried this.
Hope its of some use,
Andy